# Registraion does not work after reset security token

Tags: salesforce1-app, php, wordpress

After trying to register I receive 500 error.

There is a site (I do not know whether it is possible to insert links to other sites), I was allowed to modify it. Until Sunday, everything was ready and the customer decided to do a reset security token. After that registration ceased to work, it sends data to salesforce. In the console I see this error:

```
jquery.js? ver = 1.12.4: 4 POST http://somesite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I also checked the old version of the project on the local machine, where the registration was working exactly.

Comment: Which oAuth flow are you using